# File IO in cypher/neo4j, or via other language integration

Tags: file-io, neo4j, cypher

Is there file IO capability built into cypher/neo4j, or does one accomplish that from another language, such as by using neo4j from python or java? An example motivation is producing system documentation from a graph of knowledge about a system.

Answer (score 0):

The neo4j ecosystem provides numerous built-in ways to do file IO, depending on what aspect of neo4j you are using.

As a few examples:

1. The Cypher language has a [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/load-csv/) clause that supports importing data from CSV files.
2. The [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) plugin provides many useful procedures that inpout from or export to files.
3. The [neo4j browser](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/) provides ways to export request results (as images or as data).